# How do I dynamically create and use a database table under MVC

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, web-applications

I'm trying to figure out how to dynamically create model related tables in MVC with varying names.

I've performed many searches and just can't seem to find an example or anything about how to do this.

What I need is multiple DB tables based on the same model. The only difference between the the tables is the name. But I can't figure out how to create these tables with dynamic names, with the exception being manually execute sql queries. I'm struggling to believe that is the only way.

Below is a simplified variation of what I'm trying to do.

My model:

```
public class SomeClass
{   public int Id { get; set; }
    public int SomeValue1 { get; set; }
    public int SomeValue2 { get; set; }
}
```

utilization:

```
var context;

private void CreateTable(string strTableName, SomeClass theclass)
{
    // Create the table here using the supplied name
}

private SomeClass GetTable(string strTableName)
{   SomeClass theclass;
    // Read the table here using the supplied name
    return theclass;
}

private void workRoutine()
{   SomeClass theclass1 = new SomeClass();
    SomeClass theclass2 = new SomeClass();
    SomeClass rdclass1;
    SomeClass rdclass2;

    theclass1.SomeValue1 = 1;
    theclass1.SomeValue2 = 2;

    theclass2.SomeValue1 = 3;
    theclass2.SomeValue2 = 4;

    CreateTable("myTestName1", theclass1);
    CreateTable("myTestName2", theclass2);

    rdclass1 = GetTable("myTestName1");
    rdclass1 = GetTable("myTestName2");
}
```

Comment: If you're planning on adding tables and changing the overall schema of your database during run time, I suggest first you check and see if this is the only way to do what you want to do and second consider not using mvc/entity framework

Comment: I don't think it is the only, but I do believe that it is the cleanest  way. It would provide for a more straight forward method of coding and easier to maintain\follow. I'm sure I can do it another way, but it would be a long way around short path.

Comment: This smells really bad - more like an awful design decision than a "short path"

Comment: Why is it that you want to create tables dynamically? what is preventing you from translating the data you're going to put into these tables into rows. Creating tables on the fly is a very bad idea.

Comment: Many thanks anyway, as I have found another way; however, I feel compelled to say that the idea that creating tables on the fly is a bad idea is like hard gotos in C\C++ are bad. Personally, I don't use them; however, that is because I was originally taught they were a bad idea. 20 years of experience has taught me it is a matter of preference, and that they have their uses, be it design simplicity or otherwise. Why is it that creating tables dynamically is a bad idea? It's done all the time in other scenarios, but in MVC it is a no-no.  I don't understand that.

Comment: I wanted to create the tables for a cleaner DB design. Easier to follow. The alternative is now an array of tables and the contents are complicated to follow. Just not as clean as I would prefer. Ultimately, the results are a hierarchy structure of linked lists for account management usage. It would have been much nicer to have isolated them and reference them by name. Now is 10 tables each to grow significantly. The separate table solution would have been 3 tables with estimated 3 tables per account. They could easily have been manually traversed and more easily understood, if needed.